# Ruby ,Mechanize. How to get specific <a> tag text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

My goal is to get  "I want this text"  text.

```
<div class="class1">
<b>xxxxx</b>
<a href="http://example.com/want/xxxx">I want this text</a>
<a href="http://example.com/want/yyyy">I want this text</a>
<b>yyyyy</b>
<a href="http://example.com/unnece/xxxx">no need</a>
<a href="http://example.com/unnece/xxxx">no need</a>
</div>

<div class="class2">
<a href="http://example.com/want/xxxx">no need</a>
<a href="http://example.com/want/yyyy">no need</a>
</div>
```

I try to write code.

```
test = agent.page.search("div[@class='class1'] / a").text
```

However,I also got "no need" text

How can I do it ? I am using the gems:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'
```

I want to place commma between the text if possible...

Comment: You may try to use gem 'nokogiri', it have css selectors and methods to find many elements

Comment: @Pavel - Mechanize is a sister project of Nokogiri and includes it as a parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably lots of ways but the most obvious is:

```
agent.page.search('.class1 a[href*=want]').text
```

Comment: @pguardiario how about get the href?, Thanks

Comment: @stan just replace `.text` with `[:href]`

Answer (score 0):

I will go with css selectors like this:

```
test = agent.page.search("div.class1 > a:first-of-type").text
```

Comment: That's just the first a, he wants the first 2 a's